# magic_quotes_gpc removed since 5.4

Tags: php, deprecated, php-5.6, php-7.2, magic-quotes-gpc

I'm upgrading some code to php 7+.
This directive is removed in 5.4.
So since 5.4, this if will ALWAYS evaluate false right?

```
if (ini_get("magic_quotes_gpc"))    
{       
   some_code;
}
```

Is this for sure for php 5.5+ right?

Comment: Yes, it is gone.

Comment: And may it forever RIP!!!

Comment: if inside the if I have  "stripslashes($string);"

The striplashes will never execute, but, how should be this code replace (if (magic) + striplashes($string)  ?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/7viel

Comment: You don't need that code so remove or leave as is as it won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Magic Quotes has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

For more information see: [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)